# Passing an ID into a <select> name[][]

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, row

My javascript adds a new row to a table upon clicking a button.

I need to pass the id of that row into the multi select name, so for example if I added 5 rows to my table, I would need the 5 selects to be:

```
<select name="room[1][]" multiple="multiple">...</select>
<select name="room[2][]" multiple="multiple">...</select>
<select name="room[3][]" multiple="multiple">...</select>
<select name="room[4][]" multiple="multiple">...</select>
<select name="room[5][]" multiple="multiple">...</select>
```

My javascript to add a row is:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

            newcell.childNodes[0].value = rowCount;
        }
    }
```

I can increment the values of an input box by just using:

```
<TD><INPUT name="id[]" type="hidden" value="0"/></TD>
```

But I don't know how to increment the **name** of an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the incremented value for the input into a variable. And for the name of an attribute,  you can use that variable. So, it won't be necessary to increment the value for the name of an attribute.

Comment: I need to adjust the name of the attribute so when I post my form along with other arrays all the ID's line up